# Cannot add a user to a default virtual host in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, virtualhost

I want to add a user to a default `/` virtual host in RabbitMQ using REST API.

I am executing a following endpoint:

`PUT http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2F/user.name` and I am getting:

```
400 Bad Request: "{"error":"bad_request","reason":"vhost_or_user_not_found"}"
```

`%2F` is encoded default virtual host name: `/`.

The virtual host `/` exists in the RabbitMQ:

[image]

It is also interesting, because when I execute the same endpoint but with different virtual host name, it works:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/ble/user.name
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: "_vhost_or_user_not_found_" - are you sure it's the vhost which is not found, and not the user? Reason for asking: I cannot recreate your error - `%2F` works for me, as documented. I only get that error when I try to refer to a user which has not yet been created: `/api/permissions/%2F/i_do_not_exist_yet`. Create the user first using a PUT and `/api/users/new_user_name_here` - and a suitable body for the PUT.

Comment: @andrewJames I called the endpoint again in Postman. It worked. It seems that I have a different problem. I try to call this endpoint using RestTemplate from Spring. It fails in this execution: ``` restTemplate.put("http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2F/" + userName, "{\"configure\":\".*\",\"write\":\".*\",\"read\":\".*\"}");``` I need to investigate it. Thank you.

Comment: Missing forward slash after `%2F`.